# Use AJAX and get the values of text from the Admin Panel

Tags: ajax, pdp

I want to get the values from store->configuration.

And print that value in the PDP page using AJAX.

The value should be refresh all the time using AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a controller which can return the value using scope config.

Then create the layout file:

> catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="ajax.info" template="Vendor_ModuleName::info.phtml" after="product.info" >
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

> info.phtml

```
<div class="old">
</div>
<div class="ajax-info" id="div1">
</div>
<div class="loader"></div>
<div class="placetexthere" id="output">
</div>


<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Vendor_ModuleName/js/ajax-js":{}
        }
    }
</script>
```

> ajax-js.js

```
define([
    "jquery"
], function($) {
    "use strict";
    $.widget('test.ajax', {
        options: {
            url: 'frontname/controller/action',
            method: 'post'
        },

        _create: function() {
            this._bind();
            console.log('_create');
        },

        _bind: function() {
            var self = this;
            self._ajaxSubmit();
            console.log('_bind');
        },


        _ajaxSubmit: function() {
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: self.options.url,
                type: self.options.method,
                dataType: 'html',
                data: 'hello',

                beforeSend: function() {
                    console.log('beforeSend');
                    $('div#loader').trigger('processStart');
                },
                success: function(res) {
                    console.log('success');
                    console.log(res);
                    $('div#output').html(res);
                    $('div#loader').trigger('processStop');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        self._ajaxSubmit();
                    }, 1000);
                }       
            });
        }

    });
    return $.test.ajax;
});
```